# How do i run a logistic regression with a predictor and a response variable?

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression

Running my logistic regression, I am to plot the data i have created, and then plot the line that is described by the coefficients of your model.

```
library("dplyr")  # filter and reformat data frames
library("tidyr")  # make data tidy

# Create an empty vector will 200 variables
df_vector <- c(1:200)

# For the first 100 variables, 
for (i in 1: 100) {
    # Set the normal distribution with mean -5 and sd 5
    v1 <- rnorm(100, -5,5)

# For the second 100
for (i in 101:200) 
    # Set the normal distribution with mean 4 and sd 8
    v2 <- rnorm(100,4,8)
}

# Input the vales of v1 and v2 into a data frame 
df_vector <- data.frame(v1,v2)

# Combine the 2 columns of data into one single vector with a length of 200
Uni_dataframe <- data.frame(d = unlist(df_vector, use.names = FALSE))


# Create another vector with first half of the values = 0 and second half = 1
resp_vector <- c(1:200)

# For the first 100 variables
for (i in 1:100) {

    # Set the first 100 variables = 0
    resp1 <-(rep(0, times = 100 ))

# For the second 100 variables   
for (i in 101:200)
    # Set the second 100 variables = 1
    resp2 <- (rep(1, times = 100 ))
}

# Input both resp1 and resp 2 into a data frame
resp_vector <- data.frame(resp1, resp2)

# Combine the 2 columns of data into a single vector with length 100
Uni_resp_vector <- data.frame (d = unlist(resp_vector))
```

The 2 vectors i have created above are Uni_dataframe and Uni_resp_vector. 
I am then tasked to run a logistic regression according to the following code and function.

```
log.likelihood(params, x, y)

logistic.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

logistic.predict(xtest, fit)

log.likelihood = function(params, x, y) {

    x = cbind(rep(1, nrow(x)), x)       
    Bx.sum = params %*% t(x) 
    t1 = sum((1-y)*Bx.sum)
    t2 = sum(log(1+sapply(-Bx.sum, exp, simplify=T))) 

    likelihood = -(t1+t2)
    return(-likelihood) 
}



model <- optim(params = Uni_dataframe, fn = Uni_resp_vector, log.likelihood, data, method='BFGS')
```

However, I am unsure of what arguments to put in optim() and i am getting the error from optim: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'. Is there an issue with the 'data' argument?

Any help would be appreciated to churn out a logistic regression model. Any suggestions on how it should be plotted? thank you!

Comment: If you want to fit a logistic model in R, most people would use the `glm()` function. See this tutorial for example: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/. If you need help using this particular function, then I would ask the person that's making you use it. But it doesn't look like you've defined a variable named `data` at all so i'm not sure what you are trying to pass to the function there at all.

Comment: You're getting that error because, as @MrFlick pointed out, you don't seem to have defined `data`. In that case, the only thing in your environment called `data` is the base R function `data`, which is of improper type for that argument. It seems like this is homework, judging by "your" in "then plot the line that is described by the coefficients of your model." It's unclear what you're expecting `optim` to do, so if you've copied the code from class materials, maybe check back there...?

Comment: This also looks like one of those situations where you need to figure out what the focus of the problem really is. The majority of the code you included here is creation of a data frame, but the actual problem you're having is with using the function `optim`. Why not just clear out the code that isn't essential to solving the problem and post a representative sample of data? It might become more obvious to you what types of data you're working with

Comment: indeed, i have trouble understanding what goes into optim(). thank you nonetheless for pointing out that 'data' is causing the problem.